# Unable to find value in tuple

Tags: python

I'm building a tuple of datetimes that overlap. start_overlap and end_overlap are datetime objects.

In each 'for item in time_tuple' loop, I want to see if the time exists in the item. This comparison always fails even when the time does exist in the item being evaluated.

```
time = start_overlap
end = end_overlap
time_tuple = (...contains a bunch of items in the format of (str(time),1), ...)

while time < end:    
    if time_tuple == ():            
        time_tuple +=(str(time),1), 

    else:
        for item in time_tuple:

            if str(time) in str(item): #this never resolves to true
                print('time found in item')    
                pass

            else:
                time_tuple +=(str(time),1),

    time = time + timedelta(minutes=7.5)
```

Can you see what's wrong with my conditional statement where I check to see if str(time) is in the item?

Thanks

Comment: try making it a list. Tuples are always harder to work with.

Comment: I require a tuple. The value of 1 that I'm storing has significance and will change to 2, 3, 4, later in my code depending on the data.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, there is no instance where you need a tuple. Lists are more open, and you can change values.

Answer (score 0):

The instruction `str(time) in str(item)` compare the string representation of a `datetime` with the string representation of an item, which is a `typing.Tuple[str, int]`. This will inevitably fail.

I can not test it as I do not have a fully working codebase, but it should work by replacing the above instruction with `str(time) in item`, or, if you prefer, `str(time) == item[0]`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

change this line:

```
if str(time) in str(item):
```

to this:

```
if (str(time),1) === str(item):
```

Comment: === is not valid for python. Plus, I don't want to check for the key and value. Just the key (i.e. time).

Comment: Not wanting to check for the key and value. just the key (i.e. time).